# Boolean Inputs in Python

Tags: python, boolean

I am trying to solve this Boolean Input question but I can't figure out the answer. Here is what it says, We pass in 2 boolean inputs, cold and rainy.

You should output a single string:
('cold' or 'warm') ' and ' ('rainy' or 'dry')
based on these inputs.

('cold' or 'warm') means you should use on of the two words, depending on the input boolean value.

for example False, True = 'warm and rainy'

And here is my code:

```
isCold= sys.argv[1] == 'True'
isRainy= sys.argv[2] == 'True'

if isCold:
  print('cold and rainy')

elif isRainy:
  print('warm and rainy')

else:
  print(cold and dry)
```

I don't know what I can do to solve this.

Comment: Please add some more info.

Comment: what are you passing as an argument ?

Comment: and what is the output you’re getting?

Comment: Expected Output: cold and dry
Your Program Output: cold and rainy

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
import sys


def func1(isCold, isRainy):
    s = ''
    if isCold:
        s = s + 'cold and '
    else:
        s = s + 'warm and '

    if isRainy:
      s = s + 'rainy'
    else:
     s = s + 'dry'

    print(s)

isCold= sys.argv[1] == 'True'
isRainy= sys.argv[2] == 'True'

func1(isCold, isRainy)
```

Then, run it by using the following command in your linux terminal:

```
python3 your_file_name.py False True
```

Or if you are a Windows user:

```
your_file_name.py False True
```

Answer (score 1):

The concisest answer I can think of is:

```
temperature_description = "warm" if isWarm else "cold"
rain_description = "rainy" if isRainy else "dry"
print "{} and {}".format(temperature_description, rain_description)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Thanks for the help everyone I found out the answer.